# 'Forget + infinitive-to' or 'Forget + gerund'?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

According to Cambridge dictionary, the word forget can be followed by either infinitive or gerund. These are the sentences I took from the dictionary:

> She would never forget seeing the Himalayas for the first time [1].
>
> Dad's always forgetting (to take) his pills [2].

My difficulty is deciding which one to use in this context:

> I have to walk back to my room when I forget [to bring/bringing] the
> key. (I use the simple present to describe my routine; something I'll do if I do the other thing.)

Is there an easy way to know whether I should use infinitive-to or gerund when the verb has two possibilities like in this case? (I've learned that I must be careful to decide infinitive-to or gerund that I'll use, although it's possible to use either, sometimes it can give another different meaning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Infinitive**: To forget to do something is to *fail* to do that thing because your memory failed you.  E.g., forgetting to take your pills means that you failed to take your pills.

**Gerund**: Your memory failed you, but you didn't necessarily fail to complete a task.  E.g., "I forget meeting him."  There was no task of meeting this person that you failed at; you simply don't remember the meeting that took place.

But note that "I forget meeting him" isn't particularly elegant-sounding English.  People would more likely say, "I don't remember meeting him."  But "I'll never forget meeting him" sounds perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

*forget [gerund]* applies to the past: *I often find that I have already seen a movie but forgotten seeing it.*

*forget [infinitive]* applies to the present: the forgetting is roughly simultaneous with the thing that ought to be done.